# Java: automatic memoization

Tags: java, python, annotations, decorator, memoization

I have a few functions in my code where it makes much sense (seems even mandatory) to use memoization.

I don't want to implement that manually for every function separately. Is there some way (for example [like in Python](http://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonDecoratorLibrary#Memoize)) I can just use an annotation or do something else so I get this automatically on those functions where I want it?

Comment: After lots of looking, I finally just originated my own: https://gist.github.com/chaotic3quilibrium/7535c231bb11bd9abc5712c982c46690

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Spring 3.1 now provides a [`@Cacheable` annotation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.0.M1/spring-framework-reference/html/cache.html), which does exactly this.

> As the name implies, @Cacheable is used to demarcate methods that are cacheable - that is, methods for whom the result is stored into the cache so on subsequent invocations (with the same arguments), the value in the cache is returned without having to actually execute the method.

Answer (score 7):

I don't think there is a language native implementation of memoization.

But you can implement it easily, as a decorator of your method. You have to maintain a Map: the key of your Map is the parameter, the value the result.

Here is a simple implementation, for a one-arg method:

```
Map<Integer, Integer> memoizator = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();

public Integer memoizedMethod(Integer param) {

    if (!memoizator.containsKey(param)) {
        memoizator.put(param, method(param));
    } 

    return memoizator.get(param);
}
```

Comment: How can I implement it in a general way as a decorator of my method?

Comment: @Albert: As Benoit stated, there is not native implementation of this (i.e. you can not do this in a general way without Java hacking), since the python decorator stuff uses some "meta-information" about the function. I.e. it is possible in python to let the decorator alter the original function. This is -- as far as I know -- not possible in Java.

Comment: "you can implement it easily, as a decorator of your method." <- how can I do it as a decorator? Or what do you mean by that?

Comment: @Albert, he means decorator in the more generic term of a wrapper around another function, not in the pythonic syntax way that makes it look clean and simple.  You might be able to get what you want with AspectJ somehow, but I'm not personally familiar enough with it, and I still think it won't be nearly as easy as with python.

Answer (score 7):

I came across a memoization library called [Tek271](http://www.tek271.com/software/java/memoizer) which appears to use annotations to memoize functions as you describe.

Comment: Ah I see. It seems that the lib provides a way to create a wrapper object for your object and it automatically memoizes those functions which were marked for memoization via an annotation.

Comment: The page has moved and can now be found at http://www.tek271.com/software/java/memoizer

Answer (score 4):

You could use the [Function](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Function.html) interface in Google's [guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) library to easily achieve what you're after:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import com.google.common.base.Function;

public class MemoizerTest {
  /**
   * Memoizer takes a function as input, and returns a memoized version of the same function.
   * 
   * @param <F>
   *          the input type of the function
   * @param <T>
   *          the output type of the function
   * @param inputFunction
   *          the input function to be memoized
   * @return the new memoized function
   */
  public static <F, T> Function<F, T> memoize(final Function<F, T> inputFunction) {
    return new Function<F, T>() {
      // Holds previous results
      Map<F, T> memoization = new HashMap<F, T>();

      @Override
      public T apply(final F input) {
        // Check for previous results
        if (!memoization.containsKey(input)) {
          // None exists, so compute and store a new one
          memoization.put(input, inputFunction.apply(input));
        }

        // At this point a result is guaranteed in the memoization
        return memoization.get(input);
      }
    };
  }

  public static void main(final String[] args) {
    // Define a function (i.e. inplement apply)
    final Function<Integer, Integer> add2 = new Function<Integer, Integer>() {
      @Override
      public Integer apply(final Integer input) {
        System.out.println("Adding 2 to: " + input);
        return input + 2;
      }
    };

    // Memoize the function
    final Function<Integer, Integer> memoizedAdd2 = MemoizerTest.memoize(add2);

    // Exercise the memoized function
    System.out.println(memoizedAdd2.apply(1));
    System.out.println(memoizedAdd2.apply(2));
    System.out.println(memoizedAdd2.apply(3));
    System.out.println(memoizedAdd2.apply(2));
    System.out.println(memoizedAdd2.apply(4));
    System.out.println(memoizedAdd2.apply(1));
  }
}
```

Should print:

Adding 2 to: 1

3

Adding 2 to: 2

4

Adding 2 to: 3

5

4

Adding 2 to: 4

6

3

You can see that the 2nd time memoizedAdd2 is called (applied) to the arguments 2 and 1, the computation in the apply is not actually ran, it just fetched the stored results.

Comment: Comes more close to what I want but still too specific. Is it possible to generalize this even more so that it can take any number of parameters (and not just one)?

Comment: Guava's Function class condenses all input into a single argument.  Now, that argument's type could be a Object[], effectively allowing whatever, but reducing the effectiveness of typechecking.  Or, it would be pretty straightforward to create a new Function2 interface generisized by <F1, F2, T> for 2 arguments, a Function3<F1, F2, F3, T>, etc.

Comment: In Guava the Suppliers class has built-in memoize and  memoizeWithExpiration methods.

Answer (score 1):

[Cyclops](https://github.com/aol/cyclops) offers Memoisation for Functions, Suppliers, Callables, Predicates and by extension methods (via Method References) ([see javadoc](http://static.javadoc.io/com.aol.cyclops/cyclops-functions/4.0.2/com/aol/cyclops/functions/Memoise.html))

E.g.

Given a variable called that counts the number of time our method is actually called, we can see the memoised function actually executes the method just once.

```
int called = 0;

cached = Memoise.memoiseQuadFunction(this::addAll);

assertThat(cached.apply(1,2,3,4),equalTo(10));
assertThat(cached.apply(1,2,3,4),equalTo(10));
assertThat(called,equalTo(1));

private int addAll(int a,int b,int c, int d){
    called++;
    return a+b+c+d;
}
```