# Java compiler optimisation

Tags: java, compiler-optimization

Do I need to worry about performance in the case below and save the result of the expensive call, or does the compiler recognise it can do the expensive call once?

```
String name;
if (object.expensiveCall() != null) {
  name = object.expensiveCall().getName();
}
```

Comment: If results gets data from lets say a database, or from the network, the data changes. So logically it will not be saved.

Comment: It will simplify the code for simple cases which can be inlined and the JVM (not the javac compiler) can detect there are no side effects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compiler will not (in general) do the call just once as it may have side effects, or may be volatile in its result - it couldn't possibly know when you wanted it to ignore a second call and when you wanted it to actually make the call again. You need to save the result:

```
final ExpensiveCallResult nullableResult = object.expensiveCall();
String name;
if (nullableResult != null) {
  name = nullableResult.getName();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for something called [memoization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization). [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3934777/java-automatic-memoization) suggests that Java can't do it natively.

In general, memoization is only possible if the compiler/JIT can prove that the function has no side-effects. So I wouldn't count on it.

But is it really that hard to just save the result?

```
String name;
ObjectType temp = object.expensiveCall();
if (temp != null) {
    name = temp.getName();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How could the Java compiler know, that `expensiveCall` has no side effects? In the general case - it cannot. Also: You might recompile the class of `object` anytime without recompiling your current class. And what would happen if `expensiveCall` has got side effects *now*?  No way for automatic optimization.

BTW: The JIT-Compiler at *runtime* might have more information. But *expensive* calls are usually not considered for inlining and hence also not to further optimization steps.

Answer (score 0):

No, you will need to rewrite it to only make the call once:

```
String name;
MyResult result = object.expensiveCall();
if (result != null) {
  name = result.getName();
}
```

You can also shorten the syntax to make the assignment and check in the same line:

```
String name;
MyResult result;
if ((result = object.expensiveCall()) != null) {
  name = result.getName();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In future you can compile and decompile your class back with [JAD](http://www.varaneckas.com/jad) to see compiler optimizations.

In your case it doesn't optimize anything.